# PHPUnit: how to mock multiple method calls with multiple arguments and no straight order?

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

I need to test following function:

```
[...]
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceManager)
{

    $firstService = $serviceManager->get('FirstServiceKey');
    $secondService = $serviceManager->get('SecondServiceKey');

    return new SnazzyService($firstService, $secondService);
}
[...]
```

I know, I might test it this way:

```
class MyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testReturnValue()
    {
        $firstServiceMock = $this->createMock(FirstServiceInterface::class);
        $secondServiceMock = $this->createMock(SecondServiceInterface::class);

        $serviceManagerMock = $this->createMock(ServiceLocatorInterface::class);

        $serviceManagerMock->expects($this->at(0))
             ->method('get')
             ->with('FirstServiceKey')
             ->will($this->returnValue($firstService));

        $serviceManagerMock->expects($this->at(1))
             ->method('get')
             ->with('SecondServiceKey')
             ->will($this->returnValue($secondServiceMock));

        $serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory($serviceManagerMock);

        $result = $serviceFactory->createService();
    }
    [...]
```

or

```
[...]
public function testReturnValue()
{
    $firstServiceMock = $this->createMock(FirstServiceInterface::class);
    $secondServiceMock = $this->createMock(SecondServiceInterface::class);

    $serviceManagerMock = $this->createMock(ServiceLocatorInterface::class);

    $serviceManagerMock->expects($this->any())
         ->method('get')
         ->withConsecutive(
            ['FirstServiceKey'],
            ['SecondServiceKey'],
         )
         ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls(
            $this->returnValue($firstService),
            $this->returnValue($secondServiceMock)
         );

    $serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory($serviceManagerMock);

    $result = $serviceFactory->createService();
}
[...]
```

Both workes fine, but if I swap the ->get(xxx) lines in the createService function, both tests will fail.
So, how do I have to change the testcases which doesn't need a specific sequenz for the parameters 'FirstServiceKey', 'SecondServiceKey, ...

Comment: have you tried with `$this->any()` instead of `$this->at(0)`?

Comment: Yes, that was my first try. Leads to an error:

    Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:get> when invoked zero or more times
    Parameter 0 for invocation

Comment: yes, initially i don't read carefully your question. I hope my answer fill your needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with `willReturnCallback` or `willReturnMap` strategy, as example of `willReturnCallback`:

```
public function testReturnValue()
{
    $firstServiceMock = $this->createMock(FirstServiceInterface::class);
    $secondServiceMock = $this->createMock(SecondServiceInterface::class);

    $serviceManagerMock = $this->createMock(ServiceLocatorInterface::class);


    $serviceManagerMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('get')
        ->willReturnCallback(
            function ($key) use($firstServiceMock, $secondServiceMock) {
                if ($key == 'FirstServiceKey') {
                    return $firstServiceMock;
                }
                if ($key == 'SecondServiceKey') {
                    return $secondServiceMock;
                }
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException; // or simply return;
            }
        );

    $serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory($serviceManagerMock);

    $result = $serviceFactory->createService();
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while and so there is a new option to solve this: Change to 'Prophets'

```
public function testReturnValue()
{
    $this->container = $this->prophesize(ServiceLocatorInterface::class);
    $firstService = $this->prophesize(FirstServiceInterface::class);
    $secondService = $this->prophesize(SecondServiceKey::class);

    $this->container->get('FirstServiceKey')->willReturn(firstService);
    // And if you like
    $this->container->get('FirstServiceKey')->shouldBeCalled();

    $this->container->get('SecondServiceKey')->willReturn(secondService);
    [...]
    $serviceFactory = new ServiceFactory();

    /*
     * Little error in my example. ServiceLocatorInterface is parameter of 
     * createService() and not the constructor ;) (ZF2/3)
     */

    $result = $serviceFactory->createService(
        $this->container->reveal()
    );
    [...]
}
```

and now, it doesn't matter, in which sequence you'll make the '$serviceManager->get([...]);' calls \o/